# Wireshark: how to display packet comments?

Tags: wireshark

I'd like to change my Wireshark display to show packet comments I've added as a new column.

I added a new "custom" column and set the field to "pkt_comment". Which does indeed add the column, but instead of seeing the comment itself, I get a boolean that's set whenever there is a comment field in the packet. How can I get the comment itself to display? My mad Google skillz are failing me on this one. PS: I'm using Wireshark 3.2.3. TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [`frame.comment`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html), not `pkt_comment`.

Comment: OMG, you nailed it. Thank you!